# What is the fragile base class in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, oop, inheritance, base-class

I'm reading a book of object-c. When talking about inheritence, the book says:

> Methods use the self parameter to find the instance variables they
>   use.
>
> The Objective-C compiler knows the layout of the instance variables in
>   an object because it has seen the @interface declarations for each of
>   these classes.
>
> With this important knowledge, the compiler can generate code to find
>   any instance variable.

Then it says this can cause fragile base class problem:

> The compiler works its magic by using a “base plus offset” mechanism.
>
> Given the base address of an object—that is, the memory location of the first byte of the first instance variable—the compiler can find all other instance variables by adding an offset to that address.
>
> When you access some instance variable in a method, the compiler generates code to take the value that self holds and add the value of the offset (4, in this case) to point to the location where the variable’s value is stored.
>
> **This does lead to problems over time.**
>
> These offsets are now hard-coded into the program generated by the compiler.
>
> Even if Apple’s engineers wanted to add another instance variable to NSObject, they couldn’t, because **that would change all of the instance variable offsets**.
>
> This is called the **fragile base class problem**.
>
> Apple has fixed this problem with the new 64-bit Objective-C runtime introduced with Leopard, which uses indirection for determining ivar locations.

I don't understand why adding instance variable in NSObject can cause problem.

If NSOject changes, can't we just recompile the program so the offsets change accordinglly?

**Edit**: And what if we dont recompile, will the existing code just fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a recompile would fix things, but until you recompile, your program would be broken.

Imagine that you compile your app targeting 10.4. The compiler looks at the headers of NSObject and figures out what the appropriate offset is for each ivar in your subclass. Then 10.5 comes out and they add new ivars to NSObject. Anyone running your app on 10.5 will have problems, because the Foundation framework (which includes NSObject) was compiled against the 10.5 SDK, while your app is still relying on the layout that was present in the 10.4 SDK.

The fragile base class problem meant that Apple could not change the size of any framework class without crashing every app that did not recompile for the new SDK. While in an ideal world, developers would always release updates promptly, that's not reality. So until the fragile base class problem was fixed, Apple's hands were tied.

Answer (score 1):

If Apple adds an ivar to `NSObject`, **all** of its subclasses would need to be recompiled, meaning a number very close to the 100% of all the Objective-C code ever written.

Do you see the problem now?

It's not impossible to solve, you *just* need to have every developer to recompile their code bases, but in the meanwhile every single Objective-C program out there would be broken.

As a further reference, here's a very nice article by Greg Parker on this subject: http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/01/27/objc_explain_Non-fragile_ivars.html